# Convert string to Date() with dateFormatter

Tags: swift, date

I'm trying to convert from string date ("Apr 19, 2020") and between today's date format (Date() just the format)
this is the code that I used to convert.

```
/// Create String
                    let string = (dict["Birthday"] as? String)!
                    // Create Date Formatter
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    // Origin date "Apr 19, 2020"
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, YYYY"
                    // Convert String to Date format 2020-04-19
                    print(dateFormatter.date(from: string))
```

but when I run it I get totally different date..
2021-04-29 22:20:53.888471+0300
is there someone that can help me with this?
P.S how to remove the unnecessary parts and to leave just the date?
Thank you!

Comment: Use lowercase y for year, yyyy. You can’t remove the time part other than converting it back to string.

Comment: First of all Thank you very much for your fast response!
I did it and I got this: 2020-04-18 21:00:00 +0000, 
the day is not correct (It should be 2020-04-19) and how to remove the unnecessary parts?
but the date is still not correct, how should I fix it?

Comment: That is most likely correct if you are in a different time zone than GMT which is always used when printing a date like that. Like I said if you want to remove the time part you need another DateFormatter and convert the date to a String

Comment: Ok! got it now, Thank you very much!

Comment: The command `print(someDateObject)` **always** prints the date in UTC. Avoid that. Try using `print(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: someDateObject,dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .medium)` instead. That prints the date in your local timezone, and using a format appropriate for your locale.

Answer (score 1):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

// Origin date "Apr 19, 2020"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, YYYY"

// Convert String to Date format 2020-04-19
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
print(newDate)
```

100% ok checked

Comment: "100% ok checked", obviously not

Comment: I can read. See my first comment to the question.